# better way of passing URL string to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following in my _layout.cshtml

```
<div id="authorLoader" data-request-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Author", new { area = "Book" })"></div>
```

In js file, I retrieve the url as so:

```
var url= $('#authorLoader').data('request-url');
```

Works fine, however, I end up having 20+ div tags in my layout page.  Is there a better way to pass url strings to javascript?  Or is this recommended way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the context of this request, but could you construct a javascript array of URLs and then pass the array to the function that reads them? Or alternatively construct a JSON string. Depends on how you plan to use it.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea too.. You could have a server-side helper generate a JSON object and just do one call to one div to pull all your URLs out..

Comment: Yep, I use PHP and it's incredibly simple converting an array or object to a JSON string. Then with javascript it's very easy to parse a JSON string into an array.

Comment: Do you even need to store it in a DIV though, or could you just store the parsed JSON string (an array) in a javascript variable?

Comment: Thanks!, the array sounds like it might work. I can keep a global variable of the array of urls. Atleast, it will clean up my _layout page.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. If you run into any problems with the javascript let me know, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This is a decent way to do it.. I sometimes 'cheat' and drop in some JS right into my template, and do something like

```
<script>
    var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Author", new { area = "Book" })";
</script>
```

Its not much cleaner, but at least it saves a jquery operation.